# Visual Studio 2012 Windows 8.1 Javascript debugging - v slow keyboard response

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

If I set a breakpoint in javascript code on VS2012, Windows 8.1 RTM, when execution hits the BP and I open 'Quickwatch', and type, no text appears. There is no keyboard response but it continues to respond to mouse clicks. If I then close the dialog and halt the program, the keypresses are put into my sourcecode!

This doesn't happen with breakpoints in C#, only javascript and IE11. I never saw this in IE10/Win8, or Windows 7. I have 'disable script debugging' turned off for IE and Other.

VS2012 Ultimate + update 3, Win8.1 Pro x64 RTM (clean install, all updates installed), IE11.0.9600.16384

Update: turns out VS is responding to keypresses, at a rate on 1 every 9 seconds! If I press F10, and wait, it will step through the code 9 seconds later. Same for typing a breakpoint. Still not found a work-around

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the IE LastPass extension! Disabled it, and everything is working normally